# Firebase Storage listAll() body not executed

Tags: swift, list, firebase, firebase-storage, arkit

I am new to Firebase and Swift. My previous question was very vague due to a misunderstanding on my part. In a class named "A" for example I am trying to create an object of class "B" that contains the fetchARImageTargets function that I have below. I am trying to assign the array ARImageTargets to a var in class "A" however, the listAll completion is not returned in time, which results in the var being empty. Is there a way that I can edit my function or class to avoid the var being set prematurely?

```
let ARImageTargetStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("ImageTargets")
```

```
self.fetchARImageTargets(ref: ARImageTargetStorageRef)
```

```
func fetchARImageTargets(ref: StorageReference) {
     ref.listAll { (result, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print(error)
          }
          for prefix in result.prefixes {
            self.fetchARImageTargets(ref: prefix)
          }
          for item in result.items {
            item.getMetadata { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    var imageTarget = ARImageTarget()
                    item.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                        imageTarget.ImageURL = url
                    })
                    imageTarget.Id = metadata?.customMetadata?["Id"] as String?
                    let width = metadata?.customMetadata?["PhysicalWidth"] as String?
                    imageTarget.PhysicalWidth = CGFloat(truncating: NumberFormatter().number(from: width!)!)
                    self.ARImageTargets.append(imageTarget)
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What immediately exits? Are you waiting for the asynchronous callback?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien The listAll function doesn't enter the body it exits. Yes I am waiting to receive the error or result

Comment: @blr3 It's hard to say what's going wrong based on the information you shared. It's typically easiest to help if you include a `print` statement in your code that prints something else than you expect from it.

Comment: Right before your .. if let error = error.. line, can you print(error) and print(result) and let us know what prints out?

Comment: @purebreadd for the print(error): nil for print(result): <FIRStorageListResult: 0x283344580>. It now seems like the issue is that items are not being appended to the list.

Comment: Can you try putting the last 4 lines (imageTarget.ID ...-> self.ARImageTargets.append) right after the imageTarget.ImageURL line .. before the closure of the downloadURL. I think those 4 lines may be executing before the url is returned.

Comment: Make sure the url is actually returning as well

Comment: @purebreadd Yes for some reason the url is returning as nil. I think another issue is the var that I am setting is in the viewWillAppear method and only after that method is completed an exit is when the result from the listAll function is returned.

Comment: @purebreadd I went back and did "po url" in the console and it prints out the correct url. I am not sure why ImageURL variable is still nil.